# Need to replace a string(html content) using Javasacript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Below the code i need to replace a html "entire div" by "some string" using javascript.

Here the replace string with some HTML Content(entire div to replace) with some string

```
var replaceString = '<div style="page-break-after: always"><span style="display:none"> </span></div>';
var result = htmlContent.replace(replaceString, "SOMESTRING");
var contentArr = result.split('SOMESTRING');
```

`replaceString` is not replaced, may be because of double-quotes, colon are present in that html div string. `replaceString` don't have attribute(ID, Class), but having only STYLE attribute.

Please help me sort out this problem

How do i replace "entire div" with "some string" using javascript

Thanks in Advance

Comment: htmlContent.replace(replaceString, "SOMESTRING"); but "SOMESTRING" isnt contained in replaceString?? what are you expecting?

Comment: RegExp is purposed to handle _regular_ expressions, HTML is not regular.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, try just wrapping it in a div called string and changing its inner html.

**HTML**

```
<div id="string">
   <div style="page-break-after: always">
       <span style="display:none"></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
document.getElementById("string").innerHTML = "new string"
```

Comment: thank you for quick response. but we have no option to wrapping it in a separate div(id="string"). It is the "div content" generated by CKEditor(while using pagebreak option). I need to split the content from CKEditor using the that pagebreak div content.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out exactly why you can't replace it with "SOMETHING", because I don't know what the htmlContent variable holds. My guess is that the content that CKEditor generates may contain some white spaces you didn't expect. In that case, you may need to use Regular Expression, like:

```
var replaceString = /<div\s*style="page-break-after:\s*always">\s*<span\s*style="display:none">\s*<\/span>\s*<\/div>/;
// \s* represents 0 or more white spaces
```

I made an example on JSFiddle. Check it out.

https://jsfiddle.net/itanaka/sdbnn76h/4/